# How to setup default value of post_id

Tags: posts, database

I setup fresh wordpress.
When i create new post, post id will start not with id = 1
How to set start id of post id?

Comment: You don't. That's not how IDs work. IDs are automatically incremented, and shared by posts, pages, revisions, menu items and customiser changes. The first couple would be used by the default page and post added during install.  You should not rely on them being specific values or consecutive. Is there a problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: What is your objective? If you need to hide the post id from url, you may change permalink rule in the permalinks administration page.